# Multi Table with 4 Tabs in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to create a table that has 4 tables within it. (These are displayed with tabs for each table)

Had a look through the plugins and can't see anything that can do this. Plenty of table stuff but not with tabs.

This is what I am trying to achieve

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz6miRudGoHUUHpqSWlBMDJVMVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you try with bootstrap Tab?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a Bootstrap template, so would rather go with a plugin.